# ImageIcon with external images in a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, embedded-resource, executable-jar, imageicon

I'm doing my university project, and it runs on my IDE, but when i try to run it directly from a jar, it doesn't load any images at all. So i created a resources folder in my proyect, but apparently, it's not working, because i'm not sure of how to call them. I already read a lot of posts using the "getClass().getResource()" method, but it's giving me a null pointer exception. Any help guys? I'm leaving my code:
(Btw, it's a megaman game):

```
public GameObject(int x,int y, int velX,int velY,String archivo){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.velX = velX;
    this.velY = velY;
    principal = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
    ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(archivo);
    principal.add(imagen);
    mono = new JLabel(principal.get(0));    
    mono.setBounds(this.x,this.y,mono.getIcon().getIconWidth(),mono.getIcon().getIconHeight());
}
```

This is my main "Sprite" code, i just create other sprites which extends from this class. The "Archivo" variable, it's a string where the .png file is, here i'm putting an example of how i'm calling it:

```
public MegamanSprite(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y, 1, 1, "src/Resources/megamanpd.png");
```

}

and here it's an image of how i have my folders in my Eclipse project:
[image: My clases]

I already tried using this:

```
public GameObject(int x,int y, int velX,int velY,String archivo){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.velX = velX;
this.velY = velY;
principal = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(archivo));
principal.add(imagen);
mono = new JLabel(principal.get(0));    
mono.setBounds(this.x,this.y,mono.getIcon().getIconWidth(),mono.getIcon().getIconHeight());
}
```

but this is giving me a null pointer exception, and without it it's not. Any help will be really apreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at your jar file. Does it contain an src folder? No it doesn't, because src is where you store the sources in your *development* environment. The path of the image should be `/Resources/megamanpd.png`, because that's where the image is in the jar.

Comment: Well, in fact, yes, my Jar contains a src folder, i opened with Winrar, and there's a src folder.

Comment: @HectorHammett Does not matter when loading. Forget the `src` folder.

Comment: Then your jar is badly constructed. It shouldn't contain an src folder. The content of the jar should be identical to the content of the bin folder of your eclipse project (or whatever you decided to name the output directory of the eclipse project).

Comment: @JBNizet I absolutely agree with you. The content of the JAR is supposed to be whatever is in `src` folder is without the `src` being in the jar.

Comment: Jum... i'll try to fix that about the JAR, any ideas? I'm using eclipse, maybe i put some option trying to include everything while exporting. I'm checking the BIN folder, and well, it's placing the bin AND the src folder. Now i'm getting lost. Any Ideas?

Comment: Probably @JBNizet can help improve my answer =)

Comment: Also, right now i'm trying to run it from the IDE, not from the jar, sorry if it sounds extremely newbie but, is that a problem? I mean, i try the codes that you guys are giving my, but i try to run them from the IDE, instead of building the jar.

Comment: @HectorHammett Neah, using the `getResourceAsStream()` from IDE should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your resource as stream. This will get you an `InputStream` which you can use to load your image from a jar.

1. Get the class of your object as a `Class` using the `getClass()`
2. Use the `getResourceAsStream()` to get an `InputStream`. Remember, your `src` folder will disappear in a jar. JB Nizet pointed that out.
3. Then use `ImageIO.read()` and pass the `InputStream` to get back a `BufferedImage`
4. `BufferedImage` is an `Image` and hence you can cast it to a variable of type `Image`. So, do that.
5. `ImageIcon` has a constructor that has a constructor which accepts an `Image`.

You are done !

Comment: For some reason, i have a src folder in my jar. I oppened it with winrar and there it is. And it has all my images in it. Let me try the solution that you're giving me.

Comment: I did this, and it's giving me this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Comment: @HectorHammett What path are you entering to `getResourceAsStream`?

Comment: I tried various: "Resources/megamanpd.png","src/Resources/megamanpd.png" and "/Resources/megamanpd.png".

Comment: and in all cases you have a `null` ??

Comment: Yeah. This is driving me nuts! Everything works fine in the IDE without the getResource, but when i use that so i can build the JAR, it's not Running on the IDE.

Comment: hmm... try `YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/blah/blah/xxx.png")`

Comment: Haha love the blah blah blah png. Still not working, maybe i'm coding something wrong? I did this:
`InputStream is = GameObject.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(archivo);`
And if i put a println(is.toString()); it's telling me that it's null.

Comment: `archivo` should point properly to your image. Is it a `String` ?

Comment: And that String if i use it directly in the constructor of the ImageIcon, works perfectly. That's what i don't understand.

Comment: @HectorHammett Err... it is getting hard to understand now.

Comment: Without the all class loaders and resources, and i need the so the jar could run. If i don't do the Resources thingy, it just shows a window without images. :C!!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41940/discussion-between-hector-hammett-and-little-child)

Comment: @HectorHammett Is it an option to have the images out of the jar ? That way you can load them easily. No hassles

Comment: Well the thing is that it's a project, that i have to give it in a cd as a final project. It works fine in the IDE, but when i export it as a jar, boom, Héctor gets an F for not showing anything. Haha.

Comment: Well aparently we're running out of ideas, thanks anyways man! I'm gonna keep checking if i can fix it and will return and post the solution.

Comment: Ahem, you are mixing up relative and absolute paths. Either you are invoking `getResource` or `getResourceAsStream` on a `Class` object like `GameObject.class` then the reference is relative and might have a leading `/` to denote that the path starts at the top-level package. If you invoke the methods on a `ClassLoader` like `GameObject.class.getClassLoader()` instead, they are absolute, i.e. always starting at the top-level, so you should never put a leading `/` before it.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to guess when the only thing we have is a screenshot but by looking at your icons I have the suspicion that you `Resources` folder is excluded from the build path. In this case it is not copied to the `bin` folder and therefore not accessible by `getResource` invocations.

Try right-clicking on the `Resources` folder and choosing “Build Path”→“Include” from the popup menu. The icon should change from a generic folder to a package-like icon (it will look different from packages containing classes though). Then a `GameObject.class.getResourceAsStream( "Resources/megamanpd.png");` should work from within Eclipse.

If the build path is set up correctly, generating a jar should get the right default setup but it seems that including the `src/Resources/` folder additionally to the `bin` contents has been added manually. So you might have to fix the setup manually. Regenerating the jar with the default setup should now work to get a jar in which `getResource` works correctly.